# Java - Swing - Contador de tempo com TimeUnit.sleep

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, for, try-catch

Eu estou usando Swing no NetBeans, criando um joguinho simples de matemática (achei mais viável que uma calculadora) cujo objetivo é somar os números aleatórios dos botões ate igualar-se a um numero entre 1 e 10000, que seria mostrado aleatoriamente. Eu usei `for` para tentar alguma coisa legal, fazer algo como um simples temporizador para tornar o jogo mais difícil. Ate o momento, tirando o fato de que o Netbeans pediu para adicionar um `try`,`catch`, não apresenta nenhum erro, porém, a `jLabel` `lblGameTime` não esta contando o tempo.

Eis o meu Método (ou melhor, o que eu consegui fazer, pq eu sei que eu fiz errado, só não sei onde):

```
public void GameTime() {
    int seconds = 120;
        for (int i = seconds; i < 0; i++) {
            lblGameTime.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tela1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um Timer do Swing para isso:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ExemploTimer extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ExemploTimer frame = new ExemploTimer();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ExemploTimer() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblGameTime = new JLabel();
        lblGameTime.setBounds(10, 236, 239, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblGameTime);

        int intervaloMilissegundos = 1000;

        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            Timer timer;
            public void run() {
                ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                    private int contador = 10;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        if (contador == 0) {
                            // para o timer
                            timer.stop();
                            lblGameTime.setText("Tempo esgotado!");
                        } else {
                            lblGameTime.setText(String.format("%d restantes.", contador));
                        }
                        contador--;
                    }
                };

                // executa o actionListener a cada 1000 ms
                timer = new Timer(intervaloMilissegundos, actionListener);
                timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                timer.start();
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
    }
}
```

Abcs!